# Prepopulating fields of user edit form (also: passing {{user}} into a javascript function?)

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Basically, I'm trying to make an edit profile modal with fields that are already prepopulated by the user's original data. I passed django models into my javascript files by using these brackets {{}} but it doesn't seem to work for {{user}} (as in request.user).

This is what I did for simple fields:

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input value={{user.email}} type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

{{user.email}} successfully is set as the default value for the input. 
Is there a different way to prepopulate fields? If there is, let me know and I might not have to deal with this next situation.

My naive solution works for text fields but if I have a multiselect like:

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Native Language</label>    
    <select name="nativelanguage" id="nativedrop" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
        <option value="">Language</option>
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
        <option value="French">French</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

my solution no longer works. I want to pass `{{ user }}` into a javascript function like `myFunction({{ user }})` but it seems that this is not possible.

Could anyone give me advice on how to prepopulate fields or fix the second issue below? Thanks!

Comment: is your `js file` a separated file? where do you call it? what is the button that triggers the event?

Comment: That won't work. Better to implement an API end point. Then use that end point to get user data and per-populate the modal before showing.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar could you explain a little more? I'm not familiar with what that is..

Comment: @sy89 Search about REST API.